# How to determine, find, install and reference a proper Azure SDK package?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to properly install Azure SDK, reference it and build an application based on it.

Firstly, I am not sure if I need to install Azure SDK on top of what comes with Visual Studio 2015.

Secondly, when I visit the following url, I fall into a "rabbit hole":

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dotnet-sdk/

… it refers me to a bunch of fragmented installs here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

…. When I choose “Client libraries” in above url I get the following options: more than 100 of them!! :
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=windowsazureofficial

My application needs to use Azure Service Bus and Azure storage. How do I determine what exactly is required and what is the best way to find and install them?

With a number of fragmented packages, I think there should be a flow chart help me to determine the packages required.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest you to use [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) instead of direct download this-and-that package. WPI is much more convenient, and it installs everything needed.

For Azure SB, you will need NuGet package.

For Azure Storage, if you need to test it against your local storage first instead of trying to connect to the Azure one, you can install Azure SDK using Web Platform Installer - it will install you the Azure Storage Emulator. [Details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/).

Azure SDK, however, is a very useful piece of software when developing for the Azure.

Comment: You just referred to five different installs...  Is there any map that shows me the big picture?

Comment: Hi, i am not sure if such map exists. Microsoft has some blueprints here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/architecture-overview/ and the overall graphical overview of the platform, but i did not see any map that would say that "for use of Azure SB, you should use Azure SDK, for use of that you should not, etc". Or intro can be helpful here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-introduction-to-azure/

Comment: +I would say that the most of the Azure services have a NuGet package that you can use to add the functionality to your project. Azure SDK has emulators for cloud services and storage, and adds some deployment/templates options to the Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Alex, Can I assume that Azure SDK includes all of the NuGet packages as well as the tools and simulators? and for individual packages, I have the NuGet option in addition to SDK? Thank you for help.

Comment: Hi Allan, no, Azure SDK does not include that. It includes emulators + tools. NuGet packages should be installed through the NuGet manager/etc.

Answer (score 1):

> My application needs to use Azure Service Bus and Azure storage. How
>   do I determine what exactly is required and what is the best way to
>   find and install them?

If all you need is client libraries for `Azure Service Bus` and `Azure Storage`, you can download appropriate Nuget packages from here:

Azure Storage: http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/

Azure Service Bus: http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/

If there're other packages you would need, simply search for those on Nuget's website. For example, if I need Azure AD .Net library, I would simply search for `Azure Active Directory`.

For Azure Storage, there's a local storage emulator that gets installed along with the SDK. However you can download just the storage emulator from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/?sdk=net (search for `Azure Storage Emulator` on this page).

Please note that there's no local service bus emulator at this point of time.

**A Note About SDK**

Azure SDK is pretty comprehensive (so is Azure) and includes tools and libraries for you to build and manage different kinds of applications that can be deployed in Azure. As Alex mentioned in his answer, going down `Web Platform Installer` is the easiest as it installs everything for you that is included in the SDK.

However you can also pick the components of SDK based on your project's requirements and install them individually. For example, when you go to this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51657, you will see all the components that constitute SDK 2.9. On this page, when you click download button you will be able to select components that want to download based on your project's requirements.